# Android push notification using GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to update the UI from within onMessage.

e.g. use update progress bar, How can it be done ?

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the way the [GCM sample](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/) does things. It uses the following methods to communicate with the main activity and update the GUI:

```
static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And then uses a BroadcastReceiver to catch the intent in the main Activity:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        mDisplay.append(newMessage + "\n");
    }
};
```

So you could use a similar method to communicate with your main activity to update the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

there is good answer to figure it out and also i want you to use these codes. you can get intent by putting it on onResume in ur Activity.

put these codes in your onMessage of GCMBaseIntentService

```
if(isRunningActivity()){
        Intent pushReceivedIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PUSH);
        pushReceivedIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        context.sendBroadcast(pushReceivedIntent);
        return;
}
```

and then you can receive that intent by using receiver

```
    //register as BroadcastReceiver for Push Action
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(NotificationProcessor.ACTION_PUSH);
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // put here codes what you want
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

if you have any questions, put any comments. hope this will help you